# Set Start Value as '0' With Dynamic Data In Chart.js

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I've a problem when I used this chart with dynamic data. Does anybody know how to set start value as '0' in chart.js with dynamic data ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you add the code you already have.

Comment: Hello! Please, provide what you have tried so far. This way we will be able to answer you more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your values are displayed on the y-axis, you can define [`beginAtZero: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) for the `yAxis` `ticks` inside the chart `options`.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Alternatively you may